# Android intent put extra null pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have got a customlist, my list selected and direct my simplelist... My simple list add button, my button click start new activity (maps) and zoom to point.
I do mimplelist but click button not start activity and zoom maps...

```
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): Process: com.example.ibbmaps, PID: 1702
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.example.ibbmaps.singleadapterim$1.onClick(singleadapterim.java:119)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-30 03:46:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and click button

```
public void onClick(View v) {                   
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, acilis.class);

                    intent.putExtra("x",(arac.GETX()));
                    intent.putExtra("y",(arac.GETY()));


                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

I call function

```
Intent i = getIntent();
            // Get the results of rank

          if( getIntent().getExtras() != null)
          {

              X = i.getStringExtra("x");
            Y = i.getStringExtra("y");

              XD = Double.parseDouble(X);
              YD = Double.parseDouble(Y); 

              LatLng den = new LatLng(XD, YD);


              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(den, 13));
```

Edit
**solution of the problem**
change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, acilis.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent((this class name).this, acilis.class);
```

thanks. Every body

Comment: Called this function fragment?

Comment: use this startActivity(intent); instead of this context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: I am changing but error continues

Comment: Can you tell us what is on line 119? It should be inside your onClick method

Comment: line 119
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, acilis.class);

Comment: Where have you initialized 'context' variable?, maybe it's still `null`

Comment: private static Double XD ;
     private static Double YD ;
     private Activity context;
Extend activity in

Comment: Please edit your post and add the initialization of the context. From this line it looks like it isn't initialized.

Comment: I post my  full class

Comment: @ikb Where is your full class as you stated previously